# Required format on "Where" statement for datetime columns

Tags: sql

I've a table with some columns using datetime format (US) , is there any difference to use `'2017-01-01'` date format instead of `'2017-01-01 00:00:00.000'` datetime format on the "Where" statement of the SQL script or it is the same?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Nitpicking: `'2017-01-01'` or `'2017-01-01 00:00:00.000'` are string constants in SQL - not dates or timestamps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, no.  The first is a *date* constant; the second is a *datetime* or *timestamp* constant.  In general, when a date is converted to a date/time value, the conversion occurs at midnight when the day begins.

I prefer the simpler date format for such comparisons.

By the way, many databases support the ANSI keyword `DATE` to specify a `DATE` constant, so that would look like `DATE '2017-01-01'`, making the type explicit.